# angular no detecta los componentes creados

Tags: angular, typescript, framework, angular10

Quisiera saber, estoy aprendiendo angular, lo he instalado, todo bien, he creado mi primer proyecto, he creado mi primer componente, resulta que en este framework para que el app.component.html me lea lo que he trabajado en un component solo debo crear un etiqueda con el nombre del selector, en el app.component.html y ya, resulta que hago esto, pero al guarda no me muestra lo que tengo en el componente, solo me muestra lo que tengo creado en el app.component.html

Estoy trabajando con angular 10.

Comment: Bienvenid@. Antes de empezar es recomendable revisar las guías sobre cómo realizar preguntas https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Además para poder ayudarte es necesario que hayas realizado algún intento por tí mismo y realices la pregunta sobre el problema concreto que tienes, aportando toda la información como código o ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, trazas del error, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Debes tener una referencia de tu componente en app.module.ts para que pueda ser reconocida en tu .html

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [...],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Dentro de declarations separados entre comas(",")Una vez que agregues, sale subrayado en rojo como un error

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FooterComponent
  ],
  imports: [...],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Debes importar, busca donde se encuentra tu componente creado, debes agregar junto a los otros imports la ruta

```
import { FooterComponent } from './layout/footer/footer.component';
import {MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
```

Una vez importado, ya no debe marcar como error

Ya podes usar en cualquier .html

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```